# How to playback videos with YouTube API v3 in Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I created a Windows Store app with **C#** and **XAML** to playback YouTube videos but since [YouTube shutdown their Data API v2](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.de/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html), my app fails playing videos.

What should I do to play videos with Data API v3?

I have been using the [Microsoft Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) with this code:

**XAML**

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer 
  x:Name="videoElement" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Grid.Column="1" 
  Width="Auto" 
  Height="Auto" 
  IsFullScreenVisible="True" 
  IsFullScreenChanged="videoElement_IsFullScreenChanged" 
  MediaFailed="videoElement_MediaFailed" 
/>
```

**C#**

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("aMbM7dSCHEk", YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
videoFile = url.Uri;

if (videoFile != null) videoElement.Source = videoFile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. I had to update the [MyToolkit](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/) reference of my project. In addition I had to add [MyToolkit.Extended](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Home) to make use of the YouTube classes.

**packages.config**

```
<packages>
  <package id="MyToolkit" version="2.3.30.0" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="MyToolkit.Extended" version="2.3.30.0" targetFramework="win81" />
</packages>
```